# Ubuntu 14.04.2 ceph upgrade to Ceph 0.94.1

Tags: openstack, ceph

How are you guys doing the Ceph upgrade in Ubuntu 14.04 controlled by Juju ?

Are you upgrading the distro to 15.04 ?

Answer (score 1):

The firefly release of Ceph, as shipped in 14.04, will remain supported for the duration of the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS release.

Backports of newer Ceph versions are provided via the Ubuntu Cloud Archive (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OpenStack/CloudArchive) - the Kilo release has 0.94.2 of Ceph.

You can tweak the Ceph charm to use this source using the source configuration option:

```
juju set ceph source=cloud:trusty-kilo
```

This won't upgrade existing units (that requires a little more co-ordination that we can support with just the charm and config-changed right now).